# Recursion algorithm for multilevel report

Tags: algorithm, recursion, reporting-services, x++

I'm currently developing a multi-level SSRS report, and I'm struggling with the algorithm. I've developed a recursion class which looks like below, but the level numbers are incorrect. I want the parent record (represented by a, b, and c) to show the child records so that the child records' level = (parentRecLevel+1). Right now, the level values just increment by 1. Anyone have any advice?

```
protected BOMLevel getBomLevelItem(str itemId, int numLevel, boolean firstRec)
    while select tmpBOM
    {
        bomLevel = this.getBomLevelItem(bomLevel.ItemId, bomLevel.Level, false);
    }
```

Current Outcome (where *b1*, *c1*, and *c2* are children of *b* and *c* respectively):

```
1    a
2    b
2    b1
3    c
4    c1
5    c2
```

Wanted Outcome:

```
1    a
2    b
3    b1
2    c
3    c1
3    c2
```

Comment: In general, please only use recursion as a last resort, it is almost always inefficient.  See if there is a viable alternative to recursion.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Recursion is often the most intuitive way to express a solution. As such, it's a good way to find a working solution to a problem. Once you get a working solution, then you can worry about its efficiency. Avoiding recursion because the solution might be inefficient is an exercise in premature optimization. Make the program work; then make it efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Do not reinvent the wheel, use existing algorithms and frameworks.

I'm assuming your question is not for a training exercise, but a real world problem. If it is an exercise, try to get a good grasp of recursion in an easy to use language of your choice with a big community before coming back to x++.

Your recursion method looks incomplete, because in each recursion, you iterate through all records of `tmpBom`, which (unless you modify the records in that table somewhere else) does not make sense and will never terminate. I also don't see how this method could produce the outcome you describe. I suggest you take a look at some recursion algorithm training material to learn about the fundamental parts of a recursion.

You tagged the question [x++](/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b) and the syntax also looks very much like that. Unfortunately you did not add the information which version of [microsoft-dynamics](/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) you are using, but I will assume [dynamics-ax-2012](/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax-2012) as it is currently the most common version in use.

In this version, there is already an out-of-the-box SSRS report that will show you the structure of a bill of material. You can call the report at **Inventory management > Reports > Bills of materials > Lines**. It should be fairly easy to modify this report so that it also shows the level if the report does not already fulfill your requirements.

If you still need to implement your own solution, take a look at class `BOMSearch` and its children. It is used in several places (check the cross references) and can also used to expand/explode a bill of material.

Also note that there are a lot of articles out there that try to explain how to expand or explode a bill of material in x++ code, but as with all things on the internet, be careful: Most of them are incomplete or plain wrong.